# How to get WIFI SSID in Android 9.0(PIE)?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-9.0-pie, android-connectivitymanager, networkinfo

How to get WIFI SSID in Android 9.0(PIE)? My code is working fine till android version 8.1.0 but it is not working on Android 9.0

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            wifiInfo.getSSID();
            String name = networkInfo.getExtraInfo();
            String ssid = "\"" + wifiInfo.getSSID() + "\"";
}
```

But this code is not working on Android 9.0

Answer (score 13):

Android version 9 (Pie) changes require Location to be enabled (by the user), or the call to getConnectioInfo() will fail, even if your app has correct permissions.
This is documented in the [Android 9 changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all) (excerpt below):

---

**Restricted access to Wi-Fi location and connection information**

In Android 9, the permission requirements for an app to perform Wi-Fi scans are more strict than in previous versions. For details, see Wi-Fi scanning restrictions.

Similar restrictions also apply to the getConnectionInfo() method, which returns a WifiInfo object describing the current Wi-Fi connection. You can only use this object's methods to retrieve SSID and BSSID values if the calling app has the following permissions:

- ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
- ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

**Retrieving the SSID or BSSID also requires location services to be enabled on the device (under Settings > Location).**

---

In my case, I call the function below (only if running on Android 9+) to detect if location is enabled, prior to attempting to read the WIFI SSID.

```
public static boolean isLocnEnabled(Context context) {
    List locnProviders = null;
    try {
        LocationManager lm =(LocationManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locnProviders = lm.getProviders(true);

        return (locnProviders.size() != 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            if ((locnProviders == null) || (locnProviders.isEmpty()))
                Log.d(TAG, "Location services disabled");
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "locnProviders: " + locnProviders.toString());
        }
    }
    return(false);
}
```

If location is not enabled, I pop up a dialog that says it's required, and allows the user to jump to the location settings page (see code below):

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: My locnProviders contains a "passive" even my location is disabled. I think it should be excluded.

Comment: On a Google Pixel running Android 9, with 'Use Location' turned OFF, locnProviders.isEmpty() returns true. What platform & android version are you testing?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S9+ & Android 9

Answer (score 1):

This is related to permissions....since API level 27 you need either `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission.  You may also need `CHANGE_WIFI_STATE` for Android 9 (that's the case for wifi scan anyway as per https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan)

Comment: I already tried this, NOT WORKING, getting networkInfo.getExtraInfo() as null and wifiInfo.getSSID() as "<unknown ssid>".

Comment: Are you specifically requesting those permissions from the user?

Comment: @AbhinavTiwari since Android 6 you also have to explicitly ask user for those permissions (it's not sufficient to just declare them in manifest file) - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the ssid wifi that you are connnected to it in Android 8 with location permission, but in android 9 you have to turn on location.
read more here:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all